# Converting Parse Signup and Login Tutorial to Swift from Obj-C

Tags: ios, swift

So I have been searching for a few days for a solution to this, I am trying to use the [Parse signup and login tutorial](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views) in my Swift project. The problem is that they don't have a Swift version of the tutorial and I am running into an error that I can't fix. In the project, in the Objective-C .h header file they specify a protocol

```
DefaultSettingsViewController: UIViewController <PFLoginViewControllerDelegate,PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate>
```

and I have tried many different ways to implement this but I keep getting errors like 'cannot specify non-generic type' when I try and call it this way in the class declaration. Has anyone successfully converted the tutorial or would be able to help with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to extend a superclass, while also implementing/adhering to a number of protocols, you simply list them (comma-separated), starting with the superclass:

```
class DefaultSettingsViewController: UIViewController, PFLoginViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm yeah that seems kind of complicated and I would have to look into that more. I kinda of understand what they are doing but I am surprised that Apple has not made a way to do this, I thought almost all objective-c code was able to be converted but I guess not. Do you have another suggestion then how to do this? I am not 100% sure if you have to use the delegate protocols to accomplish their default login and sign up views.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work. I am getting a different problem now but your response answered my initial question!

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to list them after the super class. You must also add the ParseUI and Parse Headers to the project bridging header file so that the classes will be recognized.

(inside bridging header file)

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Auto-correct in Swift was not working for me - the name of the Delegate is PFLogInViewControllerDelegate - it is "LogIn" and not "Login"